# Large string not printing on the console in javascript due to string length

Tags: javascript, jquery, flask

I have been designing a flask app but while printing a large string to the console, I am getting nothing, not even an error message, here is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("form").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        var input_box_content = $('#search-query').val();
        console.log(input_box_content)
        var trancript = $(".transcript").val();
        console.log(trancript)
    })
})
```

the html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/transcript.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Transcript page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="search-query" id="search-query" placeholder="Find Something....">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit Query" id="submit-button">
    </form>
    {% for i in transcript: %}
        <h4 class="transcript">{{i['text']}}</h4>
    {% endfor %}
</body>
<!-- jquery and some js -->
<script src="../static/js/jquery.js"></script> 
<script src="../static/js/index.js"></script>  
</html>
```

Comment: And the question? If there's a length restriction then "print" the string in the DOM, copy it into the clipboard, cut it into chunks, ...

Comment: @Andreas if there is a length restriction, how can I override that